# Dollar dollar= (Dollar) object; What does this do?

Tags: java, smalltalk

```
Dollar dollar= (Dollar) object;
```

What does this snippet  in do? Is it even Java? Or Smalltalk? I found it in TDD, which i think was written with Smalltalk in mind.

Comment: To me TDD is a acronym for "Test Driven Design" - which being a concept shouldn't be related to a certain programming language... or is there another explanation for those three letters?

Comment: Yeah, Test Driven Development :) Its just that Im just a beginner, and trying to learn things the right way, instead of learning, and then unlearning stuff. You are correct in saying that it should be unrelated to any particular language. But that particular line stumped me, and hence the question!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This could be Java. It basically casts an object of generic type (perhaps just Object) to a Dollar object.

Example:

```
Object object = ObjectFactory.getObject(); // Gets object
Dollar dollar = (Dollar) object; // Cast to Dollar object, will throw an exception
                                 // if this isn't possible
dollar.dollarMethod();   // I can now call Dollar methods
```

Answer (score 4):

It creates a new variable of class Dollar, with the name dollar. Then it assigns a value to that variable by casting to Dollar a variable named object. It's valid Java code, providing there's a class named Dollar defined. But if the variable named object is not of class Dollar it might throw a ClassCastException.

Comment: It is not the **variable** that must be of class Dollar; the **instance** stored in that variable must be an instance of Dollar (or of a subclass of Dollar)

Answer (score 0):

this actually casts the generic type (Object) to Dollar type.